# Drarry fanfiction where post-war Draco and Harry wake up as their 11-year-old selves

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

The story revolves around Harry and Draco waking up one day in their 11-year-old bodies, but having the experience of their post-war selves. They have gone back in time, but everyone else is living a normal timeline.

Draco and Harry decide to try to make their seven years of Hogwarts easier by being closer but also approaching the challenges that make up each of the HP books in a smarter way (I remember that for book 1, they get their own brooms when going into the challenges protecting the Philosopher’s Stone, and fly over the chess board).

I read this a while (at least a year, probably more) ago on AO3, and I think it was a series of works where each one was supposed to correspond to one of the books. I think it was unfinished, but I don’t remember at which point it stopped.